# behind the lines

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "lines" mean in the following example sentence?

> He made no secret of his contempt for the desk-bound staff behind the lines.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lines** in this context means lines of battle. In time of war on the battlefield where the fighting is taking place. Hence **behind the lines** means to the rear where the desk bound staff are safe and stand little chance of being injured or involved in combat.